# Storing Class object in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

Please take a look at the following:

```
dispenserType type[4];
dispenserType appleJuice();
type[0] = appleJuice;
dispenserType orangeJuice();
type[1] = orangeJuice;
dispenserType mangoLassi();
type[2] = mangoLassi;
dispenserType fruitPunch();
type[3] = fruitPunch;
```

as you can see i have stored different objects in the `type` array.

The `dispenserType` class has a constructor that sets the number of items to 20.
so we have `int numberfItems` for the object `appleJuice` set to 20 so on and so forth.

The same class has also the following methods: method that decreases the `numberOfItems` by one:

```
void dispenserType::makeSale()
{
    numberOfItems--;
}
int dispenserType::getNoOfItems() const
{
    return numberOfItems;
}
```

If for example the following is called:

```
appleJuice.makeSales
cout << appleJuice.getNoOfItems() << endl;
```

then the program would display the right `numberOfItmes`, which is 19. On the other hand, if `cout<<type[0].getNoOfItems()` is called, then it would display the number 20.

That behavior leads me to think that `appleJuice` and `type[0]` are two separate objects.

My questions is, is there a way to create an array of objects without needing to declare an object and store in an array as I did it as I did?

thank you.

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile. Can you post some realistic code, including the declaration of `type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, `type[0]` and `appleJuice` are two different objects.

**Option #1** - You can use an array of objects without cloning each object:

```
dispenserType type[4];
```

**Option #2** - You can use an array of pointers instead of an array of objects:

```
dispenserType* type[4];
for (int i=0; i<sizeof(type)/sizeof(*type); i++)
    type[i] = new dispenserType();
```

And of course, you will have to delete each allocated object at some later point during execution:

```
for (int i=0; i<sizeof(type)/sizeof(*type); i++)
    delete type[i];
```

Comment: @user3397856: No problem. Did it help you to work out the problem?

Comment: @user3397856: Great, glad to have helped you. You can accept the answer by clicking on the V next to it (only if it indeed answers your question).

Answer (score 1):

You are not storing any objects, because you aren't creating any. This is a function declaration:

```
dispenserType appleJuice();
```

You need

```
dispenserType appleJuice;
```

or

```
dispenserType appleJuice{}; // C++11
```

Once you fix that, then yes, doing this

```
type[0] = appleJuice;
```

*assigns* the value of `appleJuice` to an already existing object `type[0]`. It is the same as saying

```
dispenserType a;
dispenserType b;

b = a;  // b and a are different objects
```

> My questions is, is there a way to create an array of objects without needing to declare an object and store in an array as I did it as I did?

For a plain array, the only way is to use an initialization list, because once it is initialized, all you can do is modify its existing elements. So

```
dispenserType type[3] = { dispenserType(args), 
                          dispenserType(other args), 
                          dispenserType(other args) };
```

An alternative is to construct an `std::vector<dispenserType>` and `emplace_back` elements into it.